# Distinguishing between iPhone app upgrade and app new install?

Tags: iphone, ios4

There is a situation that I am faced with which seems like it has no solution. Here it is:
I have an app on App Store. I didn't write any piece of code for this app keeping the upgrade scenario in mind. For all I could imagine, I never that I would be giving out more versions apart from the one I already have on app store. Now, the situation is that I am required to give an upgrade of my app and with in the new code, I am to identify if it is a new install of the latest version or if it is an upgrade from the older version. I don't know how to approach this as I have not coded my first version appropriately for upgrades? Anybody willing to enlighten me.

Comment: Do you store any info on the phone?

Comment: Hmmm.. you can set the version number in the target settings. Any work around with this version number? I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `appDidFinishLaunching` put a bit of code to save a user default (those get synced to iTunes with the app and last between installs) if it isn't already there (first run and fresh install). Also save which version it is.
Then if it wasn't a fresh install check if the last version saved is the apps current version number.
If the apps version number is bigger it's an upgrade and you now need to save that as the last installer version.
Else it's just the app opening.

Something like this (code untested)

```
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"alreadyInstalled"]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"alreadyInstalled"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] floatValue] forKey:@"lastVersionInstalled"];
        //.... contact server or something to say it's a fresh install
    }
    else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"lastVersionInstalled"] < [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] floatValue]){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] floatValue] forKey:@"lastVersionInstalled"];
        //The user has just upgraded
    }
    else {
        //It's neither. The app has just been opened again.
    }
```

Though you won't be able to tell things like, if the user deleted it then redownloaded it or is installing it on another device.
For more advanced info you'll probably wont to use something like Flurry analytics.
http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html

Comment: @kubi well then does the app create any files or set any defaults you can check, if so check in the didFinnishLaunching method to see if they are already there (before the app gets to the point it would create them anyway). If so it's an update. Can you say what app this is?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think this will help you.

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

will give you the current version of the app. I think you can use this to check your upgradation.

Comment: How will that help me identify if it's an upgrade or a new install. All I am going to get is version 2 as output irrespective of new install of version 2 or upgrade from version 1